# How to scrape all data from Linkedin using Python in incognito mode

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on a python project whereby I am scraping data from linkedin using selenium and beautifulsoup. My program works fine but the problem is that it gets only 25 results instead of all the results. I have gone through previous solutions to this and they are saying that I can use the page number. The problem is that to load more data, one has to scroll to the bottom and the loaded data does not change the page number.
Also after scrolling for some time, you will get a "load more" button which has to be clicked to load more items. Here is my program:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as beauty
import re
import requests
import logging
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless=new")
chrome_options.add_argument("incognito")

url_link = 'https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?currentJobId=3187861296&geoId=102713980&keywords=mckinsey&location=India&refresh=true'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options
    )
if url_link.split(".")[1] == "linkedin":
    print(f"{url_link} is found and active. Scraping jobs from it")
    response = requests.get(url_link)
    soup = beauty(response.content, "html.parser")
    jobs = soup.find_all(
                "div",
                class_="base-card relative w-full hover:no-underline focus:no-underline base-card--link base-search-card base-search-card--link job-search-card",
                )
    for job in jobs:
        try:
            job_title = job.find(
                            "h3", class_="base-search-card__title"
                        ).text.strip()
            with open("job_title.txt", "a") as f:
                print(f"Job title is {job_title}", file=f)
            job_company = job.find(
                        "h4", class_="base-search-card__subtitle"
                    ).text.strip()
            with open("job_company.txt", "a") as f:
                print(f"Job company is {job_company}", file=f)
            job_location = job.find(
                        "span", class_="job-search-card__location"
                    ).text.strip()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"warning {e}")
            continue
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Where are you scrolling to the bottom and looking for the "load more" button?

Comment: When the link loads, 25 jobs are loaded. But there may be 200 jobs. So you have to scroll to load more jobs. After scrolling for long, you get a button named load more. The auto loading stops in this button and it has to be clicked to load more jobs

Comment: I know that, but you are not doing any scrolling here.

Comment: In which part am I not doing any scrolling?

Comment: That's an odd question.  In NO part of that code are you either scrolling, looking for a button, or clicking the button.

Comment: And you are creating an instance of `webdriver.Chrome`, but you are not using it.  You are making your request with `requests`, which does not interpret the Javascript.  You need to use `driver` to fetch your page if you hope to do dynamic processing, as in the first answer below.

Comment: @TimRoberts I am asking for how to scroll and load more data. Is my question clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing your code here you used requests to make the request, and it doesn't interpret javascript. So the other companies that Linkedin shows when you open the tab are on demand while you go down the page, so the right thing would be to make the request through selenium itself and run javascript on it, perhaps it will be necessary to simulate a mouse scroll down also

Comment: Can you provide a sample program please